# mapquest drag map poi market and have the long / lat poipulate into long / lat form field

Tags: leaflet, latitude-longitude, mapquest

Having spent well over 5 hrs trying to get this working i now concede defeat and ask for assistance

there is a find long / lat mapquest leaflet tool that allows thew user to enter an address the the long / lat position is diaplyed on the map and displaying the o ords in a div above the map as you move the map pin the co ordinates change

I need to have this identical functionality working on my site (yes i am a mapquest subscriber)

wondering if anyone has the raw code that does this. The hours i have spent trying to duplicate the mapquest find long / lat topol on my site has got me nowhere

I need the long / lat to appear in a long / lat text field in a form on the page as i need to then submit that form so my site can process the long / lat values based on the final position the user has placed the map pin.

IF anyone knows where i can find the specfic code to achieve the above or a tutorial that shows the necessary steps that would be fantastic

The map quest / leaflet long / lat finder tool has so much unrelated code to what i simply need to achieve the above its impossible to get it working for me anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MapQuest geocode plugin](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/geocoding/) for Leaflet to put an address on the map. The *Geocoding and Handling POI Markers with Popups* sample shows how to grab the lat/lng returned by the geocode request.

If you need the lat/lng from a map click the grab the coordinates from the event returned by a map click event.

```
map.on("click", mapclicked);
function mapclicked(e) {
    console.log(e.latlng.wrap());
}
```